# Apple search API: Getting minimum OS supported for an App from iTunes

Tags: ios, search, itunes

Posted this on the Apple forums but got no response. I have been using the lookup API that apple provides to get App metadata from iTunes. However I noticed one piece of vital information I needed for the app that I am building.

The compatibility information is not explicitly returned as a part of the response. We do get supported devices list etc but not the minimum OS version that this application requires.

E.g. For Spotify: http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=324684580 has no information regarding the min OS version found here in the main page: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/spotify/id324684580?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D4 with OS requirements 6.0 or above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API has been updated since you posted this question - look for the following:

```
{
  "resultCount": 1,
  "results": [
    {
      ...    
      "minimumOsVersion":"6.0",
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```